# Where do I have to save project specific linters (linter() package in R)?

Tags: r, styling, linter

I am new to linter() package in R and I am trying to write my own project specific linters.

My question is:
Where do I have to save them and how can I make them visible for my linter()? I do not want to include them locally/globally to default_linters. I want to have my own list of linter rules.